# Single Sign On Integration with NetCommunity

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I want to integrate Drupal with Net Community [Black Baud](https://www.blackbaud.com) single sign on.

The approach/process flow is same like FaceBook Connect or LinkedIn integration for single sign on.

NetCommunity is just another sign-on site and behaves just like LinkedIn users.

But I am stuck with from where to start the implementation of this.
I have seen LinkedIn module to login with LinkedIn. But I want to know whether it can be done using oAuth library or not.

Comment: you can look at the accepted solution at [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39065/understanding-drupals-session-management-and-user-authentication) for start up. I am implementing a similar solution, and I just referred to other modules (didn't even install them).

Comment: can you tell me the workflow which you are adapting for developing this type of custom module

Answer (score 3):

The last time I looked into [BBNC](https://www.blackbaud.com/products/blackbaud-netcommunity) (which was two or three years ago), you had to do a two-fold approach.

First, you need to write an ASP.NET webservice on the BBNC side using their API to expose login.  This may have changed since I checked it out.  Poke around the [BBNC forums](http://forums.blackbaud.com/forums/11.aspx) to see what may already exists.

Two, you wire up [authenticate against a non-drupal database](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29917/how-can-i-authenticate-against-a-non-drupal-database/29937).  This is actually fairly easy.  I would look at the [LDAP](http://drupal.org/project/ldap) module to see how it does things.  It essentially hook_form_alter's the user_login form to add some additional validation, which checks the external database.

I would also poke through the BBNC forums to see if anyone has an [LDAP](http://drupal.org/project/ldap), [OAuth](http://drupal.org/project/oauth), or [OpenID](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!openid!openid.module/7) solution for NC.  Then you can use one of the existing solutions.  Those three modules are also good to look through for ideas on how to  do the authentication.

The question that @indrock gives is also a good read about session management.

Comment: There isn't any IP associated with forums.blackbaud.com (the second link). There is https://community.blackbaud.com, but is that the new forum of that domain?